# Setting background color for list item

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ListActivity that sets a SimpleCursorAdapter to a ListView in my XML file (android:id="@android:id/android:list"). I have five rows in a prefilled database. When the activity begins, I want to set the background of the list item view corresponding to the database row with _id 3 to Blue. This item can appear anywhere in the list because the user can add, edit and delete list items. (So I can't rely on indexing by child node number.) If the item was deleted, then I don't want to do anything.

How do I find the correct View?

Added info:
The list item is organized like so (fyi, this is an outline, not the actual XML code):

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView/>
    <TextView/>
</LinearLayout>
```

That's the outline of the layout file that I pass to the SimpleCursorAdapter constructor.

Answer (score 1):

in the bindView() method of your adapter, you can determine the _id of the row and call view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_blue_background);
would look something like this

```
public void bindView(View view, Context ctx, Cursor cursor) {
    if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"))==3)
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_blue_background);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on JoeLallouz's answer its actually the view's parent that needs to be changed (only once), plus we need some insight on the list item's layout.

```
public void bindView(View view, Context ctx, Cursor cursor) {
    if(view.getId() == R.id.known_view && cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"))==3) {
        // Works if view's parent is the root of the list item's layout
        ((View)view.getParent()).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_blue_background);
    }
}
```